# Combining World-Object and Object-Object collision detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I am working on a game in a 3D environment using OpenGL.  I am implementing a swept-ellipsoid collision detection/response system for most Object/World collisions, which works fine.

The issue I am coming up against is combining that system with an Object-Object collision detection system.  The real issue I am trying to resolve in the design phase is when looking at objects that could potentially stop or alter another object's motion (say some crates that can be moved, but act as "walls" when the player runs up against them.)

I imagine that I would have to do something similar to the following:

1. Find the displacement of the object
2. Find the earliest time that the object collides with the world (a)
3. Find the earliest time that the object collides with ANY other object (culled in the broad phase, of course)
4. Move the object along the displacement by the less of (a) or (b) and perform response
5. Iterate until the displacement is entirely used

Is this correct? This seems like it will be very expensive as I will have to check each possible colliding object every iteration of the check.

Another issue:  What about objects that push other objects:

Example, say a crate falls and pushes a player.  I would need to move the crate until it hits the player, then do an entire collision detection run for the player as it is pushed before finishing the crate's movement.  That also seems like it could get prohibitively expensive as a push may cause another push, and so on.

Any guidance is much appreciated.